# Segmentation default (core dumped)

Tags: c

```
int err = pthread_create( &p, NULL, pro, (void*)1);
```

Every time I run the program I keep getting segmentation fault, I read about it and understood that a thread is trying to read and OS is blocking it. I looked into the code to find the error, but I am having a hard time since I don't have a debugger that works well with C.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GDB (you should use it) you can get some good informations when your program crash.

First build the program with "-g"

```
gcc file.c -lpthread -g
```

Then run it inside gdb.

You will see this :

```
Thread 2 "a.out" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff781e700 (LWP 8082)]
0x0000000000400b94 in produce (arg=0x1) at test.c:84
84      int id = *(int*) arg;
```

From there it is pretty obvious that the guilty line is :

```
int id = *(int*) arg;
```

Let's see exactly what you are doing here :

You want to get that parameter so you can use it.
That is correct...

However look at how you passed the parameter to your function :

```
int err = pthread_create( &producer_thread1, NULL, produce, (void*)1);
```

You are taking the value "1" , and casting it to void *. Why not... even though you would never really want to do that except some special cases maybe... But in your specific case it is absolutely not what you want , why ?

Because inside the produce function you think it is a pointer to and int , but it is not ! it is a number (1) converted to a void * , so on your system it my have been casted to the value (1) written on 64bits but it is still a 1. Therefore when you try to dereference it , you get a segmentation fault.

try declaring thoose values as variables and passing their adress to the pthread_create function (all of them)

**EDIT**

```
 int err = pthread_create( &producer_thread1, NULL, produce, (void*)1);
```

would become :

```
 int err = pthread_create( &producer_thread1, NULL, produce, (void*)&one);
```

where the variable "one" could be a global variable like this :

```
  int one = 1;
```

but it could also be an allocated int or whatever int that HAS an adress you choose.. just don't pass a value that is NOT and address and handle it as if it was.

Hope this can help.

Comment: Everything inside main and most other parts were given to me by professor and was told not to change anything inside. I am only allowed to change `void * produce(void * arg)` and `void * consume(void * arg)`. Terminal mentioned that error had something to do with pthread_create! Some of my classmates said they didnt get any of those errors!

Comment: You can try to cast arg to a long long int... however this is NOT how you would pass parameters to pthead_create. The original code and the "technique" that i am giving you here are BAD in your use case. You will just get errors and less readable code. But if you have too for your teacher..

Comment: @HectorRoussille I am going to change the create_thread function. So just to clarity what you're trying to tell me, you want me to change `(void*)1` into a variable. For example `int a = 1;` and then inside `create_thread(... , (void*) (intptr_t) a;`. Would it be like that?

Comment: i am editing my answer to show you what i mean hold on a second

Comment: When compiling POSIX thread based source and If available for the GDB implementation, then use `-pthread` as well or even instead of `-lpthread` to compile and link.